# What is the best Way to Import 'Pocket' Bookmarks to 'Save to Google' and keep tags?

Tags: google-bookmarks

I've found a way to import my 'pocket' bookmarks to 'save to google' but it's messy and it doesn't keep the tags. I can't seem to be able to export from pocket then import to google save. Is there a better way?

Here is my method:
1) Export pocket bookmarks
2) Import to firefox bookmarks
3) Export firefox bookmarks
4) Import firefox bookmarks to chrome://bookmarks/
5) go to 'save to goole' (https://www.google.com/save/) and import google bookmarks. Works but no tags!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be an easy way to do it besides putting in the tags by hand. Firefox doesn't seem to import the tags for me; but then, Chrome doesn't seem to let me tag bookmarks anyway.

The only part I found made it slightly easier was the fact I use XMarks to syncronise my bookmarks anyway, which amazingly still works despite looking like it hasn't been touched in years with its late 00s UI and website. It took about a minute to import my (large) read it later list and archive, then about the same time to download it back to Chrome.

I did want to thank you, however, for at least giving me a pathway to move my list between services!

Comment: You did not provide a solution for OP